# Calling ksh script from system() causing segfault

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ksh

I've got a fairly well tested bit of an application I'm trying to get working on Ubuntu Linux, and having a lot of problems, seemingly with the ksh implementation.  The problem seems to manifest when it is being called by the system build command.

There is a ksh script which auto-generates a C header file from a C source file.  When I try to run it via a `system()` call in a C application, the ksh crashes with a segfault.

At the command line, I can run the command without problems, and it works correctly.  It also works in the same circumstances on all other platforms I've used (including SLES and Fedora Linux).  I can also make it work by changing the shebang line in the script to `#! /bin/bash` (most of the work it does is really in a sed script so no exotic commands are done in the shell script).

But we've standardised on ksh, mainly as it was the best shell available on older AIX versions that we still support, and it is easy to add to Linux distros if it isn't included by default.

I'm not too sure where to look on this - has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Put some code , may be something else in ur code is causing this segfault

Comment: I am not sure which code to post really.  The entire shell script is too big, and it doesn't even seem to be getting that far.  As for the C-code, it is really just doing system("ut_ext misc_lib").

Comment: Can you skinny up the script and code to just call your C function and get the same result?

Comment: Does AIX have something like `strace` nowadays? Can you shorten your shell script to just do `echo $0 $1`? Does it still work then?

Comment: Note even echo $0 $1 crashes with the same segfault!

Comment: Just re-reading my above post, I had the idea that installing shells is dead easy on Linux, and there are multiple ksh variants available.  I'm going to give pdksh a go.

Comment: It's very likely pdksh is what is installed. Can you do `echo ${.sh.version}`? If you get a result, you can trust the info and it is likely a real ksh93+. Good luck.

Comment: I get Version JM 93u 2011-02-08 as a response.  I've just added pdksh and that gives me a 'bad substitution' error.  echo $KSH_VERSION now gives '@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2'

Comment: Seems to have cured the problem!  The build now works normally with /usr/bin/ksh pointing to pdksh instead of the AT&T version.

Comment: so now you have another shell you have to install? Yikes. If you pastebin either the broken code or better yet, a small test case that illustrates the problem, I'll see if there is any way to fix this without bringing in pdksh. AT&T ksh is **the** supported ksh still actively developed by David Korn and others at AT&T. Good luck.

Comment: For info, this is only something which happens on a specific box.  As I mentioned the same code works all over the place without issue, and I found out on other Ubuntu boxes too (turns out we've got a whole team whose standard dev box is an Ubuntu VM).  I've managed to write some simple programs that crash ksh by opening a few file pointers.  I think the ksh installation on the box has got corrupted somehow.  Uninstalling/reinstalling via apt-get doesn't fix it, so presumably it's a library issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, I finally worked out the specifics causing the problem.  The most basic way is simply to open 100 file pointers to the same file, then call `system()` e.g.

```
for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  fopen( "file", "r" );
system( "script" );
```

As long as the script shebang is the AT&T ksh shell, that reliably crashes on this one box.  I found a bit of the system build leaves lots of hanging file pointers to one file.  Not enough to hit ulimit problems, but enough for this weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can fix the problem by putting the full path in the system call.
If its not finding on the path you anticipate when using ksh this could be part of the problem.